# Restore zoom to default level after mouse interactions in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

Is there a way to restore the default zoom level for `pyqtgraph` plots. I know about the small button that is displayed in the plot (bottom left corner of the plot) that restores the default zoom level. What I need is I want to restore it (after I zoom in or zoom out), from the code, when a particular event happens.

I checked the `pyqtgraph` documentation but couldn't find any similar functions.

Here is the minimum reproducible code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui  
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
w = QtGui.QWidget()
btn = QtGui.QPushButton('press me')
text = QtGui.QLineEdit('enter text')
listw = QtGui.QListWidget()
plot = pg.PlotWidget()

layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
w.setLayout(layout)
layout.addWidget(btn, 0, 0) 
layout.addWidget(text, 1, 0) 
layout.addWidget(listw, 2, 0) 
layout.addWidget(plot, 0, 1, 3, 1) 

x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
y = np.random.normal(size=1000)
plot.plot(x, y, pen=(2,3), symbol='d')

w.show()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If [the source code](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/master/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/PlotItem/PlotItem.py#L485) is analyzed, it is observed that when the button you indicate is pressed, the [`enableAutoRange()`](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/viewbox.html#pyqtgraph.ViewBox.enableAutoRange) method is called, so that is the method that has to be used:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    btn = QtGui.QPushButton("press me")
    text = QtGui.QLineEdit("enter text")
    listw = QtGui.QListWidget()
    plot = pg.PlotWidget()

    btn.clicked.connect(lambda: plot.getPlotItem().enableAutoRange())

    layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    w.setLayout(layout)
    layout.addWidget(btn, 0, 0)
    layout.addWidget(text, 1, 0)
    layout.addWidget(listw, 2, 0)
    layout.addWidget(plot, 0, 1, 3, 1)

    x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
    y = np.random.normal(size=1000)
    plot.plot(x, y, pen=(2, 3), symbol="d")

    w.show()

    app.exec_()
```