# How to CLEAR the ZOOM in a PyQtGraph PlotWidget Plot?

Tags: python, plot, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I'm using PyQt5 and PyQtGraph.  I have not been able to figure out how to clear the ZOOM-level of a plot in PyQtGraph PlotWidget.  The following code demonstrates.  It draws a red rectangle.  Then use the mouse wheel to zoom-out.  Then click "Button1" and the code calls the PlotWidget.clear() method which does clear the plotted data and redraws the same rectangle blue, but it does NOT clear the ZOOM-level.  I assumed that PlotWidget.clear() would clear the entire plot including the ZOOM-level, and I could not find a PlotWidget method to clear the ZOOM-level.  See the comment "#??? why doesn't this clear the 'ZOOM'" in the code below on line 45.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot

# *********************************************************************************************
# *********************************************************************************************

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("My MainWindow")
        self.qPlotWidget = pg.PlotWidget(self)
        self.qPlotWidget.setLabel("bottom", "X-Axis")
        self.qPlotWidget.setLabel("left", "Y-Axis")

        self.qPushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.qPushButton.setText("Button1")
        self.qPushButton.clicked.connect(self.qPushButtonClicked)
        
        self.toggle = 0
        
        self.plotData()

    def plotData(self):
        data1 = np.zeros((5, 2), float) # create the array to hold the data
        data1[0] = np.array((1.0, 10.0))
        data1[1] = np.array((1.0, 20.0))
        data1[2] = np.array((2.0, 20.0))
        data1[3] = np.array((2.0, 10.0))
        data1[4] = np.array((1.0, 10.0))

        if(self.toggle == 0):
            pen1 = pg.mkPen(color=(255,0,0), width=2) # red
            self.toggle = 1
        else:
            pen1 = pg.mkPen(color=(0,0,255), width=2) # blue
            self.toggle = 0
        self.qPlotWidget.plot(data1, pen=pen1, name="data1")

    def qPushButtonClicked(self):
        print("In qPushButtonClicked")
        self.qPlotWidget.clear() # ??? why doesn't this clear the 'ZOOM'
        self.plotData()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        size = self.geometry()
        self.qPlotWidget.setGeometry(50, 50, size.width()-100, size.height()-100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    screen = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
    w.setGeometry(100, 100, screen.width()-200, screen.height()-200) # x, y, Width, Height
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: "I assumed that PlotWidget.clear() would clear the entire plot including the ZOOM-level". What made you think that? Even in the [documentation](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/plotitem.html#pyqtgraph.PlotItem.clear) there's no mention about other aspects, and it clearly says that it just removes all items (and that's also intuitive, a function named "clear" should only remove contents, otherwise it would probably be called "reset"). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60533168), and use `self.qPlotWidget.getPlotItem().enableAutoRange()`

Comment: Thanks musicamanate.  That helps a lot.  I appreciate the feedback.